# Resource-based authorization exposes "inner" resources to the controller

Tags: .net, authorization

I'm building an ASP.NET Core Web API with an endpoint that accepts a document id, and builds a report based on the document that the report service gets from a data store.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(string id)
{   
    var report = await _reportService.GetReportAsync(id);
            
    return Ok(report);
}
```

Now, I need to add authorization, and since the authorization policy is based on a value in the resource itself, the resource must be retrieved from the data store before [authorization evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can occur:

```cs
public class DocumentAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SameAuthorRequirement, Document>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   SameAuthorRequirement requirement,
                                                   Document resource)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity?.Name == resource.Author)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class SameAuthorRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

To my knowledge, authorization needs to be done in the API project. Why? Because:

- Passing a `ClaimsPrincipal` to a repository or a service feels like breaking the single responsibility principle
- `IAuthorizationService` is a part of ASP.NET and should not be in the service
- Documentation always describes authorization in the controller

But after refactoring the service to accept the document instead, suddenly the controller method becomes quite verbose (or maybe it isn't):

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(string id)
{
    var document = await _repository.GetDocumentAsync(id);

    var authorizationResult =
        await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, document, "EditPolicy");

    if (!authorizationResult.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new UserUnauthorizedException();
    }

    var report = await _reportService.GetReportAsync(document);
            
    return Ok(report);
}
```

**Suddenly the controller is aware of, and needs knowledge about, resources that otherwise would be a business for the service only**.

Am I on the right design path here?

Comment: I would do a policy requirement and add policy handler then I have all the claims and all routes , you could get the parameters from the route and send it to your service to check , doing that way your controller will remain light and readable, let me know if you need more details so I could add a full answer

Comment: You say do the checks in the service? That would mean I do the check in some other way than using the IAuthorizationService?

Comment: No you could inject interface of resource validation service and inject it to your policy handler and just send the required parameter to your services to check if the policy requirement meet or not, doing this you will keep the business in the business layer and the controller and the api layer not aware of the actual implementation since you could add it to the infrastructure layer ( assuming you following clean arch)